# precalculated definition of variable vs initializing by calculation

Tags: c, initialization, definition

Suppose for example, I wanted to initialize my variables using a function:

```
int x[10];
void init_x(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
        x[i]=i*i;
    }
}
```

It doesn't have to be this exact function, it could be more complicated and done on a bigger array or a different int type, but anyway, the point is that the *result is deterministic*. My question is: would it be better (e.g. will my program initialize faster every time) to just calculate the result of this beforehand and just define it outright?

```
int x[10]={0, 1, 4, 9, etc...}
```

That way, I just run the initialization function once (e.g run the function, then copy+paste the results to the array definition and comment the code out) and not again and again every time I open the program. (At least that's what I assume it does)

Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

Comment: If the array is small, the execution time will be little different one way or the other. But if you later want to change the array size, or its values, the code will be more flexible if the array is computed at runtime, against you having to retype perhaps a large number of values, with the risk of typos. I would put this as an answer, but for your idea of what "better" means. An alternative might be to have a utility program that generates the source code array for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if you can do the calculations at compile-time instead of at run-time and if there are caveats?

The answer depends on the complexity of the calculations. If they are simple (deterministic as you say) you can usually do this with success. The caveats are that the code for doing the computations, can be less than easy to read and it can greatly increase compile times.

The generalization of this technique is called [meta-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), where you add one extra level of code-transformation (compilation) before the usual code -> binary transformation.

You can do limited forms of that using the pre-processor. GCC also supports some expressions that are evaluated statically. Other techniques include using [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to basically achieve parametric templates like in C++.

There are libraries that are able to perform Turing-complete computation at compile-time using the pre-processor ([P99 for instance](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/)). Usually the syntax is hairy with much convention and many idioms to learn before being productive.

In contrast to complex meta-programming I've achieved greater code-clarity and appreciation from colleagues maintaining my code, when generating code using e.g. a Perl or Python script, than when I've hacked something together with the pre-processor.

**EDIT:**

To answer your question with an example, I'll tell you that I write a lot of C-code professionally for microcontrollers with 4-16kb RAM and 16-128kb flash code space. Most of the applications live for at least a decade, and will require running updates and feature additions. That means I have to take good care not to waste resources, so I'll always prefer if something can be calculated at compile-time instead of at run-time. That saves code space at the cost of added complexity in the build-system.
If the data is constant, it also means I can place it in the read-only flash memory and save precious RAM.

Another example is in the [aes-min project](https://github.com/cmcqueen/aes-min), which is a small implementation of AES128. I think there is a build choice, so that a component in the algorithm (the S-box?) gets pre-calculated and put in ROM instead of RAM. Other symmetric encryption algorithms need to calculate some data from the key, and if the key is static, this pre-calculation-technique can be used efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, human effort is way more expensive than cpu time or disk space.  Do whatever requires the least upfront and ongoing level of human effort.  Making a complicated multiple-stage build process may save a little cpu or disk, but it will cost effort.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this depends on how long it takes to generate the variable in question.  If it takes a significant amount of run time, that's when it would make sense to precalculate it.

Here's an example of how this can be done:

genx.c (the program which precalcuates the array):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("int x[] = {");
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i){
        if (i) printf(",");
        printf(" %d", i*i);
    }
    printf(" };\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When run, this outputs:

```
int x[] = { 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81 };
```

The makefile:

```make
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra

app: app.c x.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o app app.c

x.c: genx
        ./genx > x.c

genx: genx.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o genx genx.c

clean:
        rm -f app genx x.c
```

app.c (the application file):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "x.c"

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        printf("x[%d]=%d\n",i,x[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you run `make app`, it sees that `x.c` is a dependency and first runs the target for that.  The `x.c` target is built by running `genx`, which itself is compiled by the `genx` target.

Assuming `genx.c` doesn't change, `x.c` gets built once and its contents are included wherever necessary.

Output of `app`:

```
x[0]=0
x[1]=1
x[2]=4
x[3]=9
x[4]=16
x[5]=25
x[6]=36
x[7]=49
x[8]=64
x[9]=81
```

Answer (score 1):

The initialized array must be stored in the executable and loaded from disk. If the calculations are simple, then it's possible that the processor can do the calculations faster than it can read the data from the disk. 
Which means that placing the initialized data in the executable may result in a bloated executable that starts slower, a lose-lose situation.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: would it be better (e.g. will my program initialize faster every time) to just calculate the result of this beforehand and just define it outright?

It will be faster for sure. Whether it will be significant enough for you notice depends on how complex are the calculations and how often you need to initialize the variables.

If you decide to initialize the array with hard coded numbers, I would strongly advise adding comments or code in comments that explain how you got the numbers in the first place. Otherwise, it will be a maintenance headache.

> Are there any disadvantages to doing this?

I wouldn't hard code the numbers unless there is supporting evidence that demonstrates significant savings by doing it.

Comment: Is reading an `int` from disc really faster than the CPU calculating and storing it? (Note this is about systems with mass-storage, not embedded MCUs where data and code reside ready-to-use in Flash already.)

Comment: R. Sahu, the "faster" argument is discussed in user3386109's answer: it may not be faster.

Comment: @Olaf, when an executable/dll is loaded, the data are also read at the same time. I am not aware of platforms where the data are independently loaded. Maybe there are.

Comment: @RSahu: That is not the point. Consider a fast HDD which reads at - say - 150MB/s, i.e. 37.5Million `int`s per second. I think a halfway recent desktop-CPU can much faster iterate the loop.